# getting connection string data source details

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

My settings form which takes data source details:

[image: test]

My user settings are like this

```
<userSettings>
    <rScale.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="WBServerIP" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="WBSrvUsr" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="WBSrvPwd" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="WBSrvDB" serializeAs="String">
            <value>WB</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="DCSServerIP" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="DCSSrvUsr" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="DCSSrvPwd" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
        <setting name="DCSSrvDB" serializeAs="String">
            <value>DCS</value>
        </setting>
    </rScale.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

so from this text boxes how to store details to connection string

Comment: The values you get from `My.Settings` are simply `Strings`.  There's nothing magic about them.  You use the like any other `Strings`.  If you don't know how to build a connection string then you should do some research on that.  It has nothing specific to do with application settings.

Comment: but the values i give in text boxes can be stored and retrieved ...can't  i use them to create connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};UID={2};Pwd={3}",
                                               My.Settings.WBServerIP,
                                               My.Settings.WBSrvDB,
                                               My.Settings.WBSrvUsr,
                                               My.Settings.WBSrvPwd)
```

Comment: No. This is not XML Use this inside your application.

Comment: Thanks bro this helped me a bit